# Click button to get database info (Flask)

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I'm trying to get a database item to appear on a div when i click a button on the html page. I press the button and it will give me an item which will be displayed in a div i have for this. 
I'm using Flask for the very first time. How do i acomplish this using Flask and an Ajax request?

This is what i have so far:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import sqlite3
from flask import g
DATABASE = '/Food.db'

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def hello():
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Html:

```
  <div id="square"></div>
  <button> Ask </button>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
  <script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{{
  url_for('static', filename='jquery.js') }}">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: clicking the button you need to call $.ajax() method with url, parameter (id) and success method that will update the div. return format is your choice, if it's just a small piece of html, you can return whole html and insert it into div, if it's more complex, return json and create html part in success function

Comment: But where extacly does the code for connecting to the database and saving the result fit into?

Comment: there are heaps of q&a about flask and ajax, I believe that your question (or similar) was answered already